# Connecting to MySQL 5.1 using IBM Data Studio

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL database version 5.1 hosted on a web server using IBM Data Studio 4.1. I am getting an error

```
"The JDBC driver class was not found in the specified JAR or .zip file. Click the ellipsis (...) button to update the path to the JDBC driver files.".
```

I downloaded the connector file from "http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/" but IBM Data Studio doesn't recognize this .zip file as the right .jar file.

I was able to connect using SQL Developer but it isn't as friendly as I wished for. So, can someone please help me with the right .jar file and instructions for updating data studio with the jar so that I can connect successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar processes to connect to a local derby database

Confirm that your Debrby server is running

I used the startNetworkServer.bat file on Windows 7 to start derby

Open IBM Data Studio
Navigate to Windows>Prefernces>DataManagement>Connectivity>Driver Definitions

Edit the Specific Driver you will use to connect

In my case that was Derby10.2-DerbyClient JBDC Driver Default

On the Jar List tab you will see the default driver files

In my case I updated to c:\db-derby\lib\derbyclient.jar  since my derby is installed in c:\db-derby

I had to save this new location and restart IBM Sata Studio

When I selected this connection parameter in the JDBC driver pulldown I was able to define a successful connection

Hope this helps